# etiquetas nuevas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Quiero publicar una pregunta con una etiqueta **memoria-dinamica** pero necesito una reputacion de almenos 300, cifra al que aun no llego. Me dice que se lo solicite a la comunidad que la cree. Creo que seria interesante crear una  etiqueta **memoria-dinamica-en-c** o solamente **memoria-dianmica**  por el tema de la memoria dinamica en c

Comment: Podes agregar un poco mas de contexto a la etiqueta? en que casos se usaria? cual seria la descripcion de la misma?